# Populate Dropdown in MVC with API data

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

I am relatively new to MVC, and still confused, therefore I need help with a problem.

I have created a web scraper console app where I compare two articles(where I fetch the data from a certain API), now I want to make this an MVC project where I have two dropdown lists that need to be filled with data from the above-mentioned API so that I can compare the two articles.

Unfortunately for me, I do not know how to populate these drop downs, that is, I do not know what logic goes in the controller and the model... Can someone give me a hint or recommend a good read because I am totally lost.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Something like this:
[MVC app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJQ0O.png)

Comment: Read this if you want to populate from your controller: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor. Read this link if you want to use AJAX to populate your dropdown: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/populating-dropown-with-ajax-call/

Answer (score 1):

One way to populate your dropdown lists is by using ViewData.

Let's assume that your calls to the API reside in a separate service. The API would need to return a List. In this example the List will be of a custom class: `List<CustomClass>`. Let's assume that your custom class contains a property `Id`, and a property `Name`. Your controller would look like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IApiService _apiService;

    public HomeController(
        IApiService apiService)
    {
        _apiService = apiService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Get the data from the API into the ViewData
        // In this example, Id will be the Id of the dropdown option,
        // and the Name will be what's displayed to the user

        ViewData["DataFromArticle1"] = new SelectList(
                await _apiService.GetDataFromArticle1Async(), 
                "Id", "Name");

        ViewData["DataFromArticle2"] = new SelectList(
                await _apiService.GetDataFromArticle2Async(), 
                "Id", "Name");

        return View();
    }
}
```

Now, to populate the dropdowns in your View:

```
<select asp-items="ViewBag.DataFromArticle1"></select>
<select asp-items="ViewBag.DataFromArticle2"></select>
```

**UPDATE**

The following code will call your API endpoint by AJAX. We assume that you have created a `WebApi`, and that within your `WebAPI` you have an `ArticleDataController` with a method called `GetDataFromArticle1`.

Your view:

```
<select id="dataFromArticle1"></select>
```

Your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "/api/ArticleData/GetDataFromArticle1",   
        success: function (data) {  
            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Department</option>';  
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
                s += '<option value="' + data[i].Id+ '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';  
            }  
            $("#dataFromArticle1").html(s);  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Comment: I updated my question with an image of what the app should do. Now I have two questions: The result of the compared articles should come from the API also. Do I need to make two separate web services, or should I put the entire code from the console app in the web service?

Comment: In your question, you mention that you already have an API which your console app calls to (1) get the data, and (2) compare it. In my example, the ApiService will take care of calling your API for your different tasks (i.e. getting the data, comparing the data, etc.) I don't know how your console app calls the API, but my recommendation is that you should place the code that calls your API within the ApiService. The idea here is to separate concerns within your project (your Controller does not care how you get the data or how you compare it, it only cares that the data is there).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, some things have become much clearer, I will follow your instructions and let you know how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Can I solve this problem by using ajax call instead?

Comment: Yes, you can call your API by AJAX. Take a look at this example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/populating-dropown-with-ajax-call/

Comment: I looked at this particular example, but this passes data from database. What should I put instead of database entities?

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer. To call your API from AJAX you would first need to create a WebAPI. This WebAPI will contain the same code from your console app for retrieving the article data.

Comment: Here I am again, I am trying another way to do this with something I understand more - If I get the data from the API and serialize it (in the controller), can I pass the same values in the view, and how can I do that, how to access the json data in the controller and use it in the view? I know how to populate dropdowns with json data, but this MVC thing is stumping me totally...

Comment: I would recommend you to post another question, and send me the link. It is actually recommended to ask only one question per post, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741.

Comment: Oops, sorry I did not know that, I will keep that in mind, thanks! Here is the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495005/get-json-data-from-controller-to-dropdown-in-view .