# Get JSON data from Controller to Dropdown in View

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, dropdown

I am new to MVC and do not know how to solve this problem.

In a controller I have a list (filled with Api data) serialized to JSON, I need to use this JSON data do populate a dropdown in a View.

I am confused as to what should I return from the controller, what should I be doing next, am I doing this right?

For now I have this:

Model:

```
public class Tablet {        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ManufactureDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

DataController.cs

```
 Public ActionResult GetData(Tablet tablet)
 {
     List<Tablet> data = new List<Tablet>();

      // ... Code to retrieve the data from API

     string jsonRes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

     return View(jsonRes);
 }
```

In the view I need to show the ID in a dropdown:

View.cshtml

```
<select class="dropdown" id="dropdownData"></select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Data/GetData/",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (jsonRes) {
            console.log(jsonRes[i]);
            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonRes.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + jsonRes[i].Id+ '">' + '</option>';
            }
            $("#dropdownData").html(s);
        }
    });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: are you populating your `List<Tablet> data` before serializing it?

Comment: Yes, the list is filled with API data before serialization. It is showing the data as json object in console too. So, the problem for me is passing this json to the View.

Comment: Change s += '<option value="' + jsonRes[i].Id+ '">' + '</option>'; to s += '<option value="' + jsonRes[i].Id+ '">' +jsonRes[i].Id+ '</option>';       You are only assigning value. But there is no display. Please change this as per the code I have given. Also please make sure you have the values filled in the list.

Comment: Please review this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084568/populate-dropdownlist-using-ajax-mvc-4 it is very close to your question.

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran I did that and it returns 'undefined' in the dropdown.

Comment: Then it is sure that the issue is with data. @wizardress, could you please provide the json?

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran Here you go - https://api.myjson.com/bins/6jd1s .

Comment: Have you tried Deserializing it and passing it to the view that way. Then using markup to input it into a dropdown?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339089/populating-dropdown-with-json-result-cascading-dropdown-using-mvc3-jquery-aj.  Try to return JsonResult instead of ActionResult in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are setting Value, you are not setting Text for Option Tag, you must be getting blank menu items.Have tested it using your data link and code.

```
s += '<option value="' + jsonRes[i].Id+ '">'+jsonRes[i].Id + '</option>';
```

Complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select class="dropdown" id="dropdownData"></select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/6jd1s",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (jsonRes) {
            console.log(jsonRes[i]);
            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonRes.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + jsonRes[i].Id+ '">'+jsonRes[i].Id + '</option>';
            }
             $("#dropdownData").html(s);
        }
    });
});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! but the problem is I need to take this data from a json in my controller, not from an URL :)

Comment: Are you getting data in same format as from your data link? Try logging (in console) data from data link and from controller, are they same?

Comment: I am not getting anything from the controller, while the data from the data link is as it should be. I think I am not doing something right in my controller..

Comment: return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: try Mario's answer above, instead of using
 string jsonRes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data); you can also use return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: I tried it, but it throws an error, I still think I am not passing the json data from the controller right..

Comment: "'JsonResult' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Comment: did u try this : return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: [HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
 {
     List<Tablet> data = new List<Tablet>();

      // ... Code to retrieve the data from API



return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }

Comment: is the request even reaching api method? i see you have some paramters in web method but i dont see you passing any from JS

Comment: can u repost your current controller code along with all using statements on top...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**DataController:**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    List<Tablet> data = new List<Tablet>();

    // ... Code to retrieve the data from your API

    string jsonRes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    return new JsonResult(jsonRes);
}
```

In your JavaScript:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Data/GetData/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            try {
                var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

                var $select = $('#dropdownData');
                $.each(parsedData, function(i, dataItem) {
                    $('<option>', {
                        value: dataItem.Id
                    }).html(dataItem.Id).appendTo($select);  // or dataItem.Description, or whatever field you want to display to the user
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: In my controller at 'return new JsonResult(jsonRes)'; it throws the following error "'JsonResult' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line string jsonRes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

Also your method GetdData() should return JSON. Check the following code.

```
public ActionResult GetData(Tablet tablet)
    {
        List<Tablet> data = new List<Tablet>();

        data.Add(new Tablet() { Id = 1, Country = "India", Description = "Test", ManufactureDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString() });
        data.Add(new Tablet() { Id = 1, Country = "Canada", Description = "Test1", ManufactureDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString() });

        //string jsonRes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View Should be like

```
<select class="dropdown" id="dropdownData"></select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetData/",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonRes) {
            console.log(jsonRes[i]);
            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonRes.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + jsonRes[i].Id + '">' + jsonRes[i].Id+ '</option>';
            }
            $("#dropdownData").html(s);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```